# Is there an alternative to @import url("bootstrap_cdn") layer(framework);?

Tags: css, css-layer

I recently learned about importing whole css files into `@layer`. I want to import bootstrap css for my future projects into `framework` layer, so that I can easily override bootstrap style with my `utilities` layer:

```
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css") layer(framework); 
@layer framework, utilities;
```

I also know that `@import` is render blocking, that is it stops further processing of css untill the url is downloaded. Is there a way to use `link` tag or something with `@layer` so that all the styles in the linked css file would be considered as a layer, but still won't be render blocking?